# Django Celery broken after moving secret key to environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables, celery, django-celery

I'm working on a Django project that uses Celery for periodic tasks. For improved security, I moved Django's SECRET_KEY into an environment variable. The app ran fine, so Django was certainly able to find the environment variable and set the SECRET_KEY. But an unexpected side effect was that all the regularly occurring Periodic Tasks stopped triggering. I was able to run the tasks manually from Django Admin, so the Celery workers were still alive and well, but the tasks wouldn't trigger themselves like they usually do.

The app settings and Celery config are both located in a directory called `server`. Here's the file structure:

```
-server
  -__init__.py
  -celery.py
  -settings.py
```

Before moving the secret key, it was in `settings.py` like this: `SECRET_KEY = "secret"`

After moving to an environment variable, the line in `settings.py` was like this: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")`

And here's the contents of `celery.py`, in case that's relevant:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")
app = Celery("server")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

As soon as I moved the secret key out of the environment variable and back into `settings.py`, the tasks started firing again. I'm hoping to figure out why moving the secret key broke the periodic tasks so I can move the secret key back into an environment variable without side effects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the list of [Celery configurations](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html), the setting `SECRET_KEY` or `CELERY_SECRET_KEY` or anything alike doesn't exist, so the problem may not be within Celery. Such setting is specific to Django, so I assume the problem lies when Celery initializes the Django application from the Django settings `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")`.

Assuming the environment variable `SECRET_KEY` is not set, its value would be null which is equivalent to `SECRET_KEY = None`. I tried it and both the worker and the scheduler failed.

```
$ celery --app=my_proj worker  # Start the worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
$
$ celery --app=my_proj beat  # Start the scheduler
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Things you might want to look at:

1. Make sure that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY` was set on all the instances that runs the django application `./manage.py runserver` (or gunicorn, or whatever), the celery worker `celery --app=my_proj worker`, and the celery scheduler `celery --app=my_proj beat`. Perhaps it was only set on the environment that runs the Django application and the celery worker **but not on the environment that runs the celery scheduler**.
2. **NOT ADVISABLE.** Try setting a default value for the `SECRET_KEY` such as `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", "the-value-of-the-secret-key")`.

   - **WARNING**: If the environment variable was changed, those instances that uses the fixed default value wouldn't be updated, thus you have to remember to also always update the set default value.

Comment: Thanks @Niel! Celery beat was running in a separate environment that didn't have access to the environment variable.

Comment: How did you fix it @schwartz721

Comment: @SardarFaisal My environment was made of several separate Kubernetes deployments. I had forgotten to add the SECRET_KEY as an environment variable in the deployment that handled scheduling (Celery Beat).